# Contar o número de itens selecionados numa ListBox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, userform, listbox, excel-vba

Tenho uma lista `ListBox1` em um userform configurada para múltipla seleção de itens. Há alguma função, declaração ou modo de retornar o número de itens selecionados?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que esse código deva te ajudar.

```
Dim intIndex As Integer 
Dim intCount As Integer 

With ListBox1 
    For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1 
        If .Selected(intIndex) Then intCount = intCount + 1 
    Next 
End With 
Label1.Caption = "Selecionados " & intCount & " de " & ListBox1.ListCount
```

Comment: Obrigado, @andrepaulo. Funciona! Mas só tem assim mesmo, tendo que rodar um loop?

Comment: ao que conheço .. é isso ai ...